# Eliminar marcadores y actualizarlos, google maps V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-v3

necesito eliminar los marcadores, o limpiarlos del mapa para que no se sobrepongan encima los antiguos marcadores.
lo que hace este codigo con la ayuda del `setInterval(refreshMarker, 2000);` es que llama de vuelta a los marcadores, y ahi si me esta estirando tambien los nuevos marcadores que se originan desde la base de datos de donde estoy capturando los datos para mostrarlos en el mapa, pero tengo un problema.
Al volver a llamar esta funcion `refreshMarker()` no se elimina los marcadores antiguos y se van sobreponiendo, eso hace que se cree miles de marcadores copiados uno encima del otro. Requiero una funcion que elimine los marcadores para que el `setInterval(refreshMarker, 2000);` pueda trabajar bien y que mi mapa no se llene de marcadores imitados...

```
 <script>
    var map;
        var markers = [];
                function initMap() {
                     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
                        zoom: 12
                    });
                    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
                    refreshMarker();

                    function refreshMarker(){

                    downloadUrl('complement.php', function(data) {
                        var xml = data.responseXML;
                       markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
                        Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
                            var nombre = markerElem.getAttribute('nombre');
                            var apellido = markerElem.getAttribute('apellido');
                            var cedula = markerElem.getAttribute('cedula');
                            var numero = markerElem.getAttribute('numero');
                            var nacimiento = markerElem.getAttribute('nacimiento');
                           // var direccion = markerElem.getAttribute('direccion');
                            var fecha = markerElem.getAttribute('hor');
                            var foto = markerElem.getAttribute('foto');
                            var tipo = markerElem.getAttribute('tipo');
                            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                                parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
                                parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));
                            var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
                            var strong = document.createElement('strong');
                            strong.textContent = tipo + " en: "
                            infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
          var text2 = document.createElement('strong');
                            text2.textContent = "Fecha y Hora:     "
                            infowincontent.appendChild(text2);

                            var text = document.createElement('text');
                            text.textContent = fecha
                            infowincontent.appendChild(text);
                            infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

                            var text3 = document.createElement('strong');
                            text3.textContent = "NAME:    "
                            infowincontent.appendChild(text3);
        var text22 = document.createElement('text22');
                            text22.textContent = nombre + " " + apellido
                            infowincontent.appendChild(text22);
                            infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

                            var text1 = document.createElement('strong');
                            text1.textContent = "C.I.:      "
                            infowincontent.appendChild(text1);

                            var text11 = document.createElement('text11');
                            text11.textContent = cedula
                            infowincontent.appendChild(text11);
                            infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

                            var celular = document.createElement('strong');
                            celular.textContent = "Celular:      "
                            infowincontent.appendChild(celular);

                            var cel_num = document.createElement('cel_num');
                            cel_num.textContent = numero
                            infowincontent.appendChild(cel_num);
                            infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
                            infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

                            var elem = document.createElement('audio');
                            elem.src = foto
                            elem.controls = "true";
          infowincontent.appendChild(elem); 
        var icon1 = 'img_web/icono_asdasdasdasdasdasd.gif';
                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                map: map,
                                position: point,
                                icon: icon1,
                                draggable: true,
                               // animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
                            });
                           // marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
                            marker.addListener('click', function() {
                                infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
                                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                            });
                        });

                    });

                  }


                }
                function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
                    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
                        new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
                        new XMLHttpRequest;

                    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (request.readyState == 4) {
                            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
                            callback(request, request.status);
                        }
                    };

                    request.open('GET', url, true);
                    request.send(null);
                }

                function doNothing() {}


setInterval(refreshMarker, 2000);

    </script>
    <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo primero que noto es que nunca tienes los marcadores creados en ninguna variable, para esto te recomiendo que la variable

```
var markers = [];
```

La dejes para ese fin, para guardar los marcadores creados.
lo segundo sería borrar los marcadores existentes cada vez que obtienes respuesta del servidor y finalmente utilizar una variable de alcance local para la respuesta xml

```
function refreshMarker(){
     downloadUrl('complement.php', function(data) {
         // (2) borrar los marcadores existentes
         deleteMarkers();
         var xml = data.responseXML;
         // (3) aqui hago cambio
         let markersXml = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
         //cambio esto también
         Array.prototype.forEach.call(markersXml, function(markerElem) {
            // Omito tu lógica de extracción de datos ...

            //creas tu objeto LatLng
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                        parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),    
                        parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));
            //creas tu marcador
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map : map,
                position : point,
                icon : icon1,
                draggable : true,
            });

            //agregas tu listener
            marker.addListener('click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });

            //agregar nuestro marcador a la variable principal
            markers.push(marker)
        });
}

function setMapOnAll(map) {
    //hace ciclo sobre los marcadores que hemos guardado en la variable markers
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      markers[i].setMap(map);
    }
}

function deleteMarkers() {
    setMapOnAll(null);
    markers = [];
  }
```

Te dejo [esto](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove) para que tengas información de primera mano.

**Edición**

Para aclararte, cuando creas un marcador de la forma:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map
    });
```

si miras bien, en `map:map` se está diciendo que el mapa para ese marcador es la variable map, la cual es inicializada en `initMap()` y por ende muestra el marcador en el mapa, y si se quiere dejar de mostrar el marcador solo hay que tomar el marcador y decir:

```
marker.setMap(null);
```

Te dejo la definicion oficial de la clase [Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Marker)

Y ya en cuanto a la funcion `deleteMarkers()` lo que hace es:

```
function deleteMarkers(){
   // 1 dejar de mostrar los marcadores
   setMapOnAll(null);
   //2 eliminar toda referencia a los marcadores antiguos
   markers = [];

}
```

Éxitos.

Comment: Ya he visto el ejemplo que esta en la pagina de google maps api js, pero aun no comprendo como eliminar de esta forma 
`function deleteMarkers() {
    setMapOnAll(null);
    markers = [];
  } `

 Ya que mi xml cargo en la variable markers que inicializo antes de la funcion initMap, y la lat y long pues lo cargo en point,
`markers = []`; o `point=[]`?

Comment: Asi cargo lo que traigo de mi base de datos que capturo en php y paso a una variable en js. 
 `markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');` e inicializo antes del initMap de esta forma `var markers = [];` 
La latitud y longitud cargo en la variable 
 `var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
          parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));`

Comment: Ten en cuenta que en la variable `markers` debes guardar los marcadores creados con `new google.maps.Marker()`, no la respuesta del servidor, solo mira que le he cambiado el nombre a la variable de la respuesta del servidor a `let markersXml` y luego se hace el ciclo que sobre cada uno para crear cada marcador, lo que a ti te interesa guardar son los marcadores, no la respuesta del servidor, a menos de momento.

Comment: @franmavazq he editado la respuesta para mejorar la comprensión, y he añadido algunas aclaraciones

Comment: mis marcadores estan en un archivo xml y ese creo es lo que debo limpiar o eliminar para que asi desaparezca los marcadores para volverlos a visualizar, aqui te dejo una documentacion que habla de esto, [https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps?hl=es ] de esa forma es como capturo mis datos desde php y los convierto en xml para pasarlos al javascript. y mas o menos de esta forma se deberia de borrar?  [http://www.w3big.com/es/dom/dom-nodes-remove.html ]

Comment: Intenta los cambios propuestos. Saludos